# Is there a way to know how much damage minions deal?

Tags: path-of-exile

Unlike other active skills if I hover my mouse over the skill a tooltip appears with detailed information including damage, summoning skills do not show damage in the tooltip.

Is there a way to know in the game? Or is there a tool/website that can calculate it?

**EDIT:**

I'm asking this question specifically for my necromancer build and the summoning skills I use are raise zombies, spectres, skeletons, and animate guardian.

Comment: No Raging Spirits? I found them to be an excellent source of damage.

Comment: @Sjoerd oh yeah of course with raging spirits. I've just forgotten to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic HP and damage of minions are determined by gem level and then multiplied by the sum of all bonuses (from passive skills, from support gems, and from equipment mods). Basic stats have no effect on minions.

As far as I'm aware there's no calculator for this - [PoB](https://github.com/Openarl/PathOfBuilding/releases) gets close but doesn't cover everything.